# Spark writing Parquet array<string> converts to a different datatype when loading into BigQuery

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, parquet

Spark Dataframe Schema:

```
    StructType(
        [StructField("a", StringType(), False),
        StructField("b", StringType(), True),
        StructField("c" , BinaryType(), False),
        StructField("d", ArrayType(StringType(), False), True),
        StructField("e", TimestampType(), True)
        ])
```

When I write the data frame to parquet and load it into BigQuery, it interprets the schema differently. It is a simple load from JSON and write to parquet using spark dataframe.

BigQuery Schema:

```
            [
    {
        "type": "STRING",
        "name": "a",
        "mode": "REQUIRED"
    },
    {
        "type": "STRING",
        "name": "b",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "type": "BYTES",
        "name": "c",
        "mode": "REQUIRED"
    },
    {
        "fields": [
        {
            "fields": [
            {
                "type": "STRING",
                "name": "element",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            }
            ],
            "type": "RECORD",
            "name": "list",
            "mode": "REPEATED"
        }
        ],
        "type": "RECORD",
        "name": "d",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "type": "TIMESTAMP",
        "name": "e",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    }
    ]
```

Is this something to do with the way spark writes or they way BigQuery reads parquet. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Should ArrayType(StringType().... be ArrayType(StringType,...

Comment: It is a pyspark thing. In spark it is not a function but in pyspark it is a function. Correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the intermediate file format (parquet by default) that the [spark-bigquery connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector) uses.

The connector first writes the data to parquet files, then loads them to BigQuery using BigQuery Insert API.

If you check the intermediate parquet schema using [`parquet-tools`](https://pypi.org/project/parquet-tools/), you would find something like this the field `d` (ArrayType(StringType) in Spark)

```sh
 optional group a (LIST) {
    repeated group list {
      optional binary element (STRING);
    }
  }
```

Now, if you were loading this parquet yourself in BigQuery using `bq load` or the BigQuery Insert API directly, you could be able to tell BQ to ignore the intermediate fields by enabling [`parquet_enable_list_inference`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet#list_logical_type)

Unfortunately, I don't see how to enable this option when using the spark-bigquery connector!

As a workaround, you can try to use `orc` as the intermediate format.

```scala
       df
        .write
        .format("bigquery")
        .option("intermediateFormat", "orc")
```